# I want to run this in task scheduler

Tags: powershell, task, scheduler, wmic, intune

`wmic product where "name like 'Forti%%'" call uninstall /nointeractive`

I tried to run this without reboot but it would not uninstall the program.

`wmic product where "name like 'Forti%%'" call uninstall /nointeractive|wmic && shutdown /a`

This will reboot immediately and we do not want this to happen to users. So, I am thinking that I would like to run this as a task scheduler to run it at a specific time through Intune.

This is going to be done through Intune and not through regular method as shown in this article here.

https://credibledev.com/how-to-deploy-a-scheduled-task-in-intune/

So, I am not sure how to have this executed in Task Scheduler in the program/script. Should I write save this as a vbs script and execute it from a network share or how would I do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the purpose of the pipe in your second command? The parameter `/a` for the command `shutdown` cancels and ongoing shutdown.